# PowerBi - How to show multiple total columns in Matrix?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I have a slicer from which I can select weeks that I want to show on a matrix. Currently, the matrix only shows the total column at the end of all columns basically summing up all the values.

But I want to show multiple total column (One after each month). Like after the End Of Weeks of one month a total column and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply create a `Calculated column` or `Measure` to solve this problem. Actually, you can use some logic with `Calculated column`, but there is a more efficient way. To achieve the goal, you have to create `Calculated table` based on your date column. You can use that logic to create any custom label for your visuals.

Before we start diving into deep DAX here, let's create a calendar table.

```
Calendar = 
VAR _minSalesDate = CALCULATE( MIN( Sales[Date] ), ALL( Sales ) )
VAR _maxSalesDate = CALCULATE( MAX( Sales[Date] ), ALL( Sales ) )
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR( _minSalesDate, _maxSalesDate ),
    "Month", MONTH( [Date] ),
    "MonthYear", MONTH( [Date] ) & "-" & YEAR( [Date] )
)
```

Now, when we have the table with our dates and additional fields, we can start creating a solution for this particular case.

Create a new calculated table as follows:

```
CustomCategories = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Calendar', 
            'Calendar'[Date], 
            'Calendar'[Sorter]
        ),
    "Key", 'Calendar'[Date],
    "Label", 'Calendar'[Date], 
    "LabelSorter", 'Calendar'[Sorter]
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'Calendar', 
                'Calendar'[Date], 
                'Calendar'[MonthYear],
                'Calendar'[Sorter]
            ),
            "Key", 'Calendar'[Date],
            "Label", 'Calendar'[MonthYear]
        ),
        "LabelSorter", CALCULATE( MAX( 'Calendar'[Sorter] ), ALLEXCEPT( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[MonthYear] ) ) + 0.5
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'Calendar',
                'Calendar'[Date],
                'Calendar'[Sorter]
            ),
            "LabelSorter", CALCULATE( MAX( 'Calendar'[Sorter] ), ALL( 'Calendar' ) ) + 1
        ),
        "Key", 'Calendar'[Date],
        "Label", "Total",
        "LabelSorter", [LabelSorter]
    )
)
```

Note that the last part of above DAX adding `Total` is optional.

Once the table has been created, go to the *Data view*, select `CustomCategories` table, select `Label` column and sort the column by `LabelSorter` (you will find an option on the ribbon). Then go back to your *Model view* and set a relationship between `CustomCategories` and your Fact table  on `Date` column.

When you have done with all stuff above, switch back to the *Report view*. Remove the date column from your table visual and replace it with the newly created `Label` from `CustomCategories` table.

Now you should see the desired results.

Hope that helps!

Regards,
Arek